# eigenvectors of real symmetric matrix can be scaled to be real

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

**Problem Statement:**
Suppose $A$ is a real symmetric matrix in $R^{n\times n}$. Then the eigenvectors of $A$ can be *scaled* to be real.

**My Attempt:**
Let $\lambda\in R$, $v\in C^{n}$ satisfy $A \mathbf{v}=\lambda \mathbf{v}$. Then since $A$ and $\lambda$ are both real, $A\bar{\mathbf{v}}= \lambda \bar{\mathbf{v}}$, showing that the conjugate of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue. This is enough to show that $\textrm{Re}\,\mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{v}+\bar{\mathbf{v}})$ and $\text{Im}\, \mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{v}-\bar{\mathbf{v}})$ are eigenvectors of the same eigenvalue since $A\left(\frac{\mathbf{v}\pm \bar{\mathbf{v}}}{2}\right)=\frac{A\mathbf{v}\pm A\bar{\mathbf{v}}}{2}=\frac{\lambda \mathbf{v} \pm \lambda \bar{\mathbf{v}}}{2}=\lambda\left(\frac{\mathbf{v}\pm \bar{\mathbf{v}}}{2}\right)$. If $\lambda$  is not a repeated eigenvalue, then every eigenvector of $\lambda$ is linearly dependent and $\textrm{Re}\,\mathbf{v} =\alpha\mathbf{v}$ for some $\alpha\in C$. I don't know what to do when $\lambda$ is repeated however.

Intuitively, one expects this result since the eigenvectors are solutions to (degenerate) linear systems of real variables, and the solution to linear systems of real variables are real modulo a choice of scaling.

**Resolution:** Consider the identity matrix with complete eigenspace spanned by $\mathbf{v}_1=[1,i]^T$ and $\mathbf{v}_2=[i,1]^T$. There is no scalar which makes either eigenvectors real upon multiplication, showing that the original statement is only true in general for matrices with non-repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: Your statement is correct. But why is it a problem if one eigenvalue has multiplicity more than one. After all you are considering a symmetric matrix. So algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue of the matrix is same as its geometric multiplicity.

Comment: I think my edit closes the problem and addresses your comment.

Comment: The eigenvectors of identity matrix of order $2$ can be considered as $[1,0]^T$ and $[0,1]^T$ which can be written as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: The problem reduces to knowing when there exists an $\alpha \in C$ such that if $\mathbf{v}$ is a complex eigenvector, then $\alpha\mathbf{v}$ is totally real.